# DOS with NTFS support

Tags: boot, ntfs, ms-dos, freedos

I have a Skylake generation laptop, no OS, but has all the partitions created using GPARTED. Now I would like to install OS to it, running the installation from a hard drive.

As far as I know I would need to run the following command, in order to allow notebook to boot from `C:` partition, and start setup:

```
bootsect.exe /nt60 C:
```

The problem is that I cant find any software that allows me to execute this command. I have tried using tools like Hirens, but when I try to run `NTFS4DOS`, It detects `NTFS` partitions, but does not initialize them.

So, what software/tool Can I use (and how) to execute `bootsect.exe`, which is already located on my `C: partition (NTFS)`. My laptop contains only "USB 3.X" (no DVD).

Comment: I doubt that even when you are able to run this command it would allow your system to boot to an environment where you can access things like Windows setup. More likely it will repair the boot sector of your harddisk but it doesn't install some DOS like sys.com of the old days did.

Comment: ``bootsect.exe`` has nothing to do with DOS. It is WinPE program. You need to boot in WinPE (From Windows CD -> Recovery or MSDART).

Comment: What operating system are you trying to install exactly?

Comment: DOS with NTFS support wouldn't help you run bootsect.exe - you need a winpe disk. there WAS dos with ntfs support - avira had a bootdisk a looooong time ago but this would do you no good there.